# Increment ID from last row google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I coded something for google apps script. It is to increment ID +1 based on the last row. Everything is working so far except for the numbering of the new ID, instead of appearing as a number.

**The result appears as R-NaN** instead of `R-002` or something similar

What do you think should I revise in my code? Thank you.

```
function new_item() {

  // Get current spreadsheet
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Set date to today in update field at the top of the sheet
  var now = new Date();
  mysheet.getRange(1,4).setValue(now);
  
  // Last non-empty row
  var rlast = mysheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("Last row = " + rlast);
  
  // Insert Row below
  mysheet.insertRows(rlast+1);
  var r = rlast+1;
  
  // Copy format from row above
  var sourcerange = mysheet.getRange(rlast + ":" + rlast);
  var targetrange = mysheet.getRange(r + ":" + r);
  sourcerange.copyTo(targetrange, {formatOnly:true});
  
  // Col. 2 : Risk identity
  var riskid = mysheet.getRange(rlast,2).getValue();
  if (riskid.length > 3){
    // Extract number ex. 3
    var riskidnb = riskid.substring(1,riskid.length);
    // Increase risk number +1
    riskidnb++
    // Convert to string "0004"
    var s = "000" + riskidnb
    // Write risk nb i.e. "R004"
    mysheet.getRange(r,2).setValue("R-"+ s.substring(s.length-4))
  }

``´
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

Your code really depends on the value of the cell in column B last row:

```
  var riskid = mysheet.getRange(rlast,2).getValue();
```

There are two scenarios but I believe the second applies to your issue:

1. If the value in the cell is a number (e.g. 35233) then `riskid` will be an **integer** and therefore `riskid.length` will return `null` and as a result the `if` condition will evaluate to `false`. In this case, you can either use `getDisplayValue` or `toString()` instead to get the number as string and then you can apply `.length` to it:

   ```
   var riskid = mysheet.getRange(rlast,2).getValue();
   ```
2. If the value in the cell is a string (e.g. `R112`) then the `if` condition will evaluate to `true`. If you do that:

   ```
   var riskidnb = riskid.substring(1,riskid.length);
   ```

   `riskidnb` will be `112` but this is still a **string** and therefore if you do `riskidnb++` you will get `NAN` like the issue you have right now. In order to fix that, convert `riskidnb` to integer:

   ```
   var riskidnb = parseInt(riskid.substring(1,riskid.length));
   ```

   then you can do `riskidnb++` and finally convert it back to string:

   ```
   var s = "000" + riskidnb.toString();
   ```

---

### Solution:

```
function new_item() {

  // Get current spreadsheet
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Set date to today in update field at the top of the sheet
  var now = new Date();
  mysheet.getRange(1,4).setValue(now);
  
  // Last non-empty row
  var rlast = mysheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("Last row = " + rlast);
  
  // Insert Row below
  mysheet.insertRows(rlast+1);
  var r = rlast+1;
  
  // Copy format from row above
  var sourcerange = mysheet.getRange(rlast + ":" + rlast);
  var targetrange = mysheet.getRange(r + ":" + r);
  sourcerange.copyTo(targetrange, {formatOnly:true});
  
  // Col. 2 : Risk identity
  var riskid = mysheet.getRange(rlast,2).getValue();
  if (riskid.length > 3){
    // Extract number ex. 3
    var riskidnb = parseInt(riskid.substring(1,riskid.length));
    // Increase risk number +1
    riskidnb++
    // Convert to string "0004"
    var s = "000" + riskidnb.toString();
    // Write risk nb i.e. "R004"
    mysheet.getRange(r,2).setValue("R-"+ s.substring(s.length-4))
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: example]