# Incrementing ID again from last row google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

last week I asked something here [Increment ID from last row google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680059/increment-id-from-last-row-google-apps-script)

Everything was working well but then again, when I used WP1-1000 as a starting row, the result is still appearing as  WP1-0NaN

```
var riskid = mysheet.getRange(rlast,2).getValue();
  if (riskid.length > 3){
    // Extract number ex. 3
    var riskidnb = parseInt(riskid.substring(1,riskid.length));
    // Increase risk number +1
    riskidnb++
    // Convert to string "0004"
    var s = "000" + riskidnb.toString();
    // Write risk nb i.e. "R004"
    mysheet.getRange(r,2).setValue("WP1-"+ s.substring(s.length-4))
  }
```

I tried changing/increasing/decreasing the **riskid.length**, **var s**, and **s.length-4** from the code but still no avail. The result still appears as "WP1-0NaN"

From my question, the string is already inverted into an integer, but it still appears as NaN when I changed it to WP1.

Also, it seems the code from my last question only workds if there is only 1 letter like in the solution.

I literally tried everything for 2 hours and going mad now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

- That is because in your previous question, the `id` has the structure
  of `R-002` but now you are using `3` letters before the `-`:
  `WP1-1000`. You can now use `4` instead of `1` and it will work:

  `parseInt(riskid.substring(4,riskid.length));`
- However, a more generic approach would be to substring after `-`, therefore you can use `indexOf` to find that position:

  `parseInt(riskid.substring(riskid.indexOf('-')+1,riskid.length));`
- You can apply the same logic for the last line. Instead of hardcopying `WP1-` you can just get the text before and including `-`:

  ```
  riskid.substring(0,riskid.indexOf('-')+1);
  ```

### Solution:

```
  var riskid = mysheet.getRange(rlast,2).getValue();
  if (riskid.length > 3){
    // Extract number ex. 3
    var riskidnb = parseInt(riskid.substring(riskid.indexOf('-')+1,riskid.length));    
    // Increase risk number +1
    riskidnb++
    // Convert to string "0004"
    var s = "000" + riskidnb.toString();
    // Write risk nb i.e. "R004"
    var start = riskid.substring(0,riskid.indexOf('-')+1);
    mysheet.getRange(r,2).setValue(start + s.substring(s.length-4))
  }
```

Comment: hello again Marios, thanks it worked. Appreciate your answer as well, I have been learning javascript/google app script for 2 weeks so still a pretty noob. Take care