# Stop the loop after the "code" is posted at the last row - google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am bit stuck here and trying to figure out the following:

1. How increment the id (code) if it reaches Item-00010 or Item-00100..and so on? Is it better to start the value string to "Item-1000" rather than Item-00000? I don't know if it makes any difference.
2. How to stop the code when it reaches the last row (with values) but somehow the value is still getting posted in an empty row (see screenshot an example)

I do have a check to skip if the code and time are blank, it appears that it does not work for row#5. I only want to post the new code when there is a value in column B.

How this code works (adopted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803101/incrementing-id-again-from-last-row-google-apps-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)) is to check if there is an existing code in column A. If yes, assign a new code by incrementing the last digit to 1.

TIA!

[image]

Here is the snippet of the code I am using:

```
function createCode() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('FormResp');
 var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
 var sheet_Range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, LR, sheet.getLastColumn());
 var sheet_Values = sheet_Range.getValues();
    
 for (var x = 0; x < sheet_Values.length - 1; x++) {
        var code = sheet_Values[x][0];
        var time = sheet_Values[x][1];
        var status = sheet_Values[x][2];

    if (code && time == "") { continue; }

    if (((code == "" && time != "" && status == "") || (code && time != "" && status == ""))) {
      var prevRowData = sheet.getRange(x + 2, 1).getValue();

      if (prevRowData.length > 4) {
    
            var codeId = parseInt(prevRowData.toString().substring(prevRowData.indexOf('-') + 1, prevRowData.length));
    
            codeId++
            var newCodeId = '0000' + codeId.toString();
    
            var start = prevRowData.toString().substring(0, prevRowData.indexOf('-') + 1);
    
            sheet.getRange((x + 2) + 1, 1).setValue(start + newCodeId);
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your current example is not reproducible.

Comment: If you obtained the correct data in the firsst place you would not have to worry about it but you have not supplied that portion of the code so it makes it difficult to assist you.

Comment: I updated the code. That's pretty much what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `s`, `sheetResp`, and `timestamp` are not declared.
- About your 1st question of `How increment the id (code) if it reaches Item-00010 or Item-00100..and so on? Is it better to start the value string to "Item-1000" rather than Item-00000? I don't know if it makes any difference.`, if you want to use the same length of the number value, how about using the zero padding?
- About `How to stop the code when it reaches the last row (with values) but somehow the value is still getting posted in an empty row (see screenshot an example)`, I think that the reason for this issue might be due to `var sheet_Range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, LR, sheet.getLastColumn());`. In the case of `var sheet_Range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, LR, sheet.getLastColumn());`, the values are retrieved from the 2nd row to the next row of the last row.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, your showing script was modified.

```js
function createCode() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Modified
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('FormResp');
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow(); // Modified
  var sheet_Range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, LR - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); // Modified
  var sheet_Values = sheet_Range.getValues();
  for (var x = 0; x < sheet_Values.length - 1; x++) {
    var code = sheet_Values[x][0];
    var time = sheet_Values[x][1];
    var status = sheet_Values[x][2];
    if (code && time == "") { continue; }
    if (((code == "" && time != "" && status == "") || (code && time != "" && status == ""))) {
      var prevRowData = sheet.getRange(x + 2, 1).getValue();
      if (prevRowData.length > 4) {
        var codeId = parseInt(prevRowData.toString().substring(prevRowData.indexOf('-') + 1, prevRowData.length));
        codeId++
        var newCodeId = String(codeId).padStart(5, "0"); // Modiifed
        var start = prevRowData.toString().substring(0, prevRowData.indexOf('-') + 1);
        sheet.getRange((x + 2) + 1, 1).setValue(start + newCodeId);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

As another approach, when `getValue` and `setValue` are used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) When this point is reflected, how about the following modification?

```js
function createCode2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('FormResp');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var sheet_Values = range.getValues();
  sheet_Values.forEach((r, i, a) => {
    const [code, time, status] = r;
    if (code && time == "") return;
    if ((code == "" && time != "" && status == "") || (code && time != "" && status == "")) {
      if (i == 0) {
        a[i] = ["item-00001", time, status];
      } else {
        let [prefix, suffix] = a[i - 1][0].split("-");
        const newSuffix = String(Number(suffix) + 1).padStart(5, "0");
        a[i] = [`${prefix}-${newSuffix}`, time, status];
      }
    }
  });
  range.setValues(sheet_Values);
```

#### Modified script 3:

As another approach, in your situation, how about using the number format? When the number format is used, the actual value can be managed as a number value while the display value is like `item-#####`. When this point is reflected, how about the following modification?

I'm not sure whether this approach is included in your expected result. If this was not included in your goal, please ignore this.

```js
function createCode3() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('FormResp');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow).setNumberFormat('"item"-00000');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var sheet_Values = range.getValues();
  sheet_Values.forEach((r, i, a) => {
    const [code, time, status] = r;
    if (code && time == "") return;
    if ((code == "" && time != "" && status == "") || (code && time != "" && status == "")) {
      a[i] = [i == 0 ? 1 : i + 1, time, status];
    }
  });
  range.setValues(sheet_Values);
}
```

#### Testing:

When the above scripts are used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I do not know your actual situation. So, when your actual situation is largely different from your showing image, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this. If the above-modified scripts cannot be used in your actual situation, can you provide more information for correctly replicating your actual situation? By this, I would like to modify the script.

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Thank you for the comprehensive suggestions and explanation, really helpful. I tried the 1st one. Modifying the sheet range to "lr - 1" (I thought I had this originally on my code) and also the "sheet_Values.length - 1" (I added this) seems to solve the item#2 on my question, I should have thought about this awhile go but didn't. Using the zero padding also worked for item#1 above. I learned something new today. I will review the other two suggestions you posted.

Comment: @user7935276 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting like this:

```
function createCode() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('FormResp');
  var lr = sheetResp.getLastRow();
  var rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, lr - 1, sh.getLastColumn());//The number of rows is the lastrow - startrow + 1
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  for (var x = 0; x < vs.length; x++) {
    var code = vs[x][0];
    var time = vs[x][1];
    var status = vs[x][2];
```

Comment: Thank you Cooper. For some reason, I thought I had the range where the "lr-1" (# of rows) set to this but I must have overlooked it when trying to copy the code here.  Adding the "vs.length - 1" solves the issue to stop the code at the last row with values.